# Add data to a form, server side

Tags: php, forms, security

I have a form that sends POST data to a distant server wich I do not control.

The form needs to send a private key (that I believe has nothing to do on the user side) and I'm not confident with putting it in a hidden field as I'm required to.

Is there any way to send the POST data to a PHP script on my own server, that would add the missing key and re-send the POST data to the distant server ?

Comment: Why are you not using `hidden` field?

Comment: Store your key in database. Send its ID in hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From HTML, you can set the POST action to one of your PHP page and then from that PHP page, you can do a cURL request to another server by adding private key in addition of POST data given from HTML form

**form.html**

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="repost_data.php">
     <input type="text" name="field1" value="" />
     <input type="text" name="field2" value="" />
     ...
     ...
</form>
```

**repost_data.php**

```
<?php
$postArr = $_POST;
$postArr['private_key'] = 'private-key';

$ch = curl_init("http://another-server/posturl"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArr); 
curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Comment: CURL is my friend ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

1. send the post data to a page on your server itself
2. add the key you want to to the post araay by `$_POST['keyname'] = $privatekey`
3. now submit the value through the ajax call to the 3rd party server you want or make a curl request to the server

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with cURL (see http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).